# Spring Boot @Controller refuses to work with @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I used [this tutorial](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/27/using-mysql-in-spring-boot-via-spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate/) to build Spring Boot application. It appeared super easy at first glance but I ran into number of problems right away. When trying to access `/hi` or `/thing` tomcat 7 returns `404 error`. How to fix it?

```
  @Controller
    public class MainController {

        @Autowired
        ParserService parserService;

        @RequestMapping("/thing")
        public Record thing() {
            return new Record();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/hi", method= RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String displayStartPage(){
    return "{hello}";
        }
    }
```

**Application**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "go")
@EntityScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(Application.class);
        }
}
```

**RecordDao**

```
@Transactional
@Service("recordDao")
public interface RecordDao extends CrudRepository<Record, Long> {
}
```

PS. Here I had to add `@Service("recordDao")` because IntelliJ was warning that  `Cannot Autowire bean.` although in tutorial this line is not presented.

**UPDATE1**

Project structure:

[image]

**UPDATE2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>123</groupId>
    <artifactId>log-parser</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <name>Log Parser</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>Application</start-class>
        <version.jackson>1.9.13</version.jackson>
        <guava.version>16.0.1</guava.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
           <!-- <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>

        <!--Joda Time-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate validator -->

       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Apache Commons-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Persistence-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--jackson-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jackson}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Guava -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet Api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->


        <!-- TEST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ning.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-duplicate-finder-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20080701</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java EE -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**UPDATE3**

I found no useful information in catalina log neither in IntelliJ debug window...

**UPDATE4**

**THE NEW POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>123</groupId>
    <artifactId>event-log-parser</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <name>Event Log Parser</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>Application</start-class>
        <guava.version>16.0.1</guava.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
           <!-- <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>

        <!--Joda Time-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate validator -->

       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Apache Commons-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Persistence-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--jackson-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Guava -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet Api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->


        <!-- TEST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ning.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-duplicate-finder-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20080701</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java EE -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**UPDATE5**

When I run it as maven spring-boot goal it gives error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: go.service.ParserService go.controller.MainController.parserService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'parserService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: go.dao.RecordDao go.service.ParserService.recordDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [go.dao.RecordDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: what is the fully qualified package name of your Application? what package is the `MainController` in?

Comment: What is the base package of you project? I guess it starts in "go".

Comment: Can you please post the log file with the errors? Also please post your pom.xml

Comment: Given that it's Spring Boot, start with removing `basePackages` from the `@ComponentScan` annotation, removing `@EntityScan`. As you're trying to use Spring Data, you should also remove `@Transactional` and `@Service` from the `RecordDao` interface.

Comment: Definitely need to see the logs. They'll list handler mappings, among other things.

Comment: What logs are you talking about? Where can I find them?

Comment: Tomcat log: `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Jan/2015:....] "GET /hi HTTP/1.1" 404 955`

Comment: What would you expect to happen? The `/thing/ URL will try to find a view named `thing` which you probably don't have. The returned value `Record` will be added to the `Model`. You probably expected it to return the `Record` as JSON. The second one should return a String but I doubt that it works because you have conflicting jackson versions (1 and 2) in your maven pom. So I would first suggest to fix your dependencies.

Comment: my new pom updated. but `\hi` returns `404` but it's wrong.

Comment: 1) Probably your Controller IS working - put a breakpoint; send a request - see if the corresponding method is called. 2) read the docu on Controller - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html 3) read the docu on ModelAndView 4) checkout @RestController annotation 5) checkout ResponseEntity - http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

Comment: In controller, change return type to String, and dont return Record(), return the name of the JSP/JSF page you have example : return "page_name_without_extension". In that JSP page, you can create a form, or a table in HTML and you wont get 404.

Comment: Why on earth were you trying to return the domain object is beyond me, but you might wanna create a JSP page, I can post an example if you like, but you also might wanna read some basics.

Comment: I need to return JSON. I expect than domain object will be transformed to JOSN....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `Application` class in a package (e.g. "go"). Otherwise the Spring Data repository scan won't work (it would have to scan all the jar files on the classpath).

Comment: Your pom has a lot of cruft in it as well (e.g. all the jackson, validation and injection dependencies are already included transitively).

Comment: Why given than Application.java resides in root path it fails to scan? I really don't understand...

Comment: If it's in the default package Spring doesn't even ask it to scan (it would take forever).